# can I sync contacts, calendars and music from Android to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sync, android

The only thing preventing me from moving over to Ubuntu completely is my iPhone.

I'd happily consider switching to an Android phone if it had proper sync support in ubuntu.

I'd like to sync

- contacts (Google contacts)
- calendars (Google calendar)
- music (mostly mp3)

to Android under Ubuntu fairly easily.

1. Can this be done?
2. What software would I sync to on the Ubuntu side?

Comment: The iPhone doesn't use Android - are you looking to change your iPhone to an Android device?

Comment: I have an iphone but would happily switch to android if it supported Ubuntu. I would rather immerse myself in linux since that's where my professional dev work gets deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting a new phone because the iPhone is definitely not running Android.

Android already syncs w/ all google services using the data connection on your device. Syncing music might be as simply as copying files to the Android device.

UPDATE:

Ditching the iphone may be an expensive proposition given contract fees, potentially switching carrier, new phone, etc.

I see two easier options (assuming you've got a recent intel mac)

1) Dual boot Ubuntu/OSX

2) Run Linux in a VM. Get your hands on [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) and run linux simulatenously with OSX (assuming you've got a intel mac). You could try with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) as well.

Comment: To really learn an OS well you need to spend time in it and customise it. At the moment I'm using a mac, but deploying my professional work on Ubuntu. I'd be better off immersing myself in Ubuntu - and the only thing tethering me to OSX is the iphone. If android got me out of that then it'd be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One service promises to sync with Android contacts, etc, provided you have the Ubuntu One Android App installed and signed in.